# How to model cable failure as a cummulative fatigue failure of individual fibers in fiber bundle model

Tags: python, model, fibers

This requires (linear) damage accumulation rule. Assume global load sharing. Specifically, incorporate into your model the possibility of reducying fiber diameters due to corrosion, where proximity to outer surface is accounted for by a simple function of distance.
Use widgets to display the outcome

I have the following code as a basis:

```
    """
    This functions initalized the system and the load sharing matrix lls_mat
    """
    np.random.seed(run["seed"]) #seed random number generator
    strength  = sys["sweib"]*np.random.weibull(sys["mweib"],(sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"])) #get strength values
    stiffness = sys["emod"]*np.ones((sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"])) #populate stiffness matrix
    damage    = np.zeros((sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"]))    #initialize damage matrix
    stress    = np.zeros((sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"]))    #initialize loading matrix
    avalanche = np.zeros((sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"]))    #initialize damage history matrix
    lls_mat   = np.zeros((sys["ncx"],sys["ncx"]))    #initialize load sharing matrix
    #calculate load shearing matrix that is applied like a stencil
    for i in range(sys["ncx"]):
        for j in range(sys["ncy"]):
            if sys["pbs"]:#only even numbers allowed
                i1 = i; j1 = j;
                if i > sys["ncx"]/2: i1 = sys["ncx"]-i
                if j > sys["ncy"]/2: j1 = sys["ncy"]-j
                dist=math.sqrt(i1**2 + j1**2);
            else:
                dist = math.sqrt( i**2 + j**2 );
            if dist>0: lls_mat[i,j] = 1 / ((dist)**sys["gamma"])
    p = np.append(lls_mat[:,-1:0:-1],lls_mat,1)
    p2 = p[-1:0:-1,:]
    lls_mat = np.append(p2,p,0)
    run["strain"] = np.array([0.])        #clear strain evolution
    run["stress"] = np.array([0.]),       #clear stress evolution 
    run["avalanchesize"] = np.array([0.]) #clear damage evolution
    return lls_mat, strength, stiffness, damage, stress, avalanche, run

def increment_strain(strength,stress):
    """
    This functions increments stress to the failure of the next weakest intact fiber
    """
    capacity   = strength-stress
    min_idx    = np.where(capacity == np.amin(capacity))
    stress_inc = strength[min_idx[0],min_idx[1]]-stress[min_idx[0],min_idx[1]]
    stress     = stress + stress_inc; 
    capacity   = strength - stress
    min_index  = np.nonzero(capacity<=0.)
    tobreak    = [min_index] #list of elemets that need breaking.
    return tobreak, stress, stress_inc

def damage_fibers(tobreak,damage):
    """
    This functions markes damaged fibers in the damage matrix
    """
    for i in range(len(tobreak[0][0])):
        damage[tobreak[0][0][i],tobreak[0][1][i]]=1    
    return damage

def load_sharing(sys,lls_mat,tobreak,damage,stress,strength):
    """
    This functions redistributes the load of broken fibers to intact ones that are not marked for failure
    """
    for i in range(len(tobreak[0][0])):
        f1, t1 = int(sys["ncx"]-1-tobreak[0][0][i]), int(sys["ncx"]-1-tobreak[0][0][i]+sys["ncx"])
        f2, t2 = int(sys["ncy"]-1-tobreak[0][1][i]), int(sys["ncy"]-tobreak[0][1][i]+sys["ncy"]-1)
        x = lls_mat[f1:t1, f2:t2]
        intact = x * ( 1 - damage )
        stress = stress + strength[tobreak[0][0][i],tobreak[0][1][i]]*intact/np.sum(intact)
        strength[tobreak[0][0][i],tobreak[0][1][i]] = 1000 * sys["sweib"] # so it will not be found as new failing elmt
    return stress, strength

def new_inc_stress(strength,stress,avalanche,load_inc):
    """
    This functions works within avalanches and checks what fibers fail due to load redistribution
    """  
    capacity = strength - stress
    min_index = np.nonzero( capacity<0. )
    tobreak = [min_index] #list of elemets that need to be broken.
    for i in range(len(tobreak[0][0])): avalanche[tobreak[0][0][i],tobreak[0][1][i]] = load_inc #store damage evolution pattern
        
    return tobreak, avalanche

def studyFBM(syssize=100,gamma=0,weibullmod=3,CharStr=700,Emod=1000,pbs=False, seed = 1):
    
    # system and simulation parameters
    sys={"ncx":   syssize,    # number of fibers in x-/y-direction (gerade Zahlen)
     "ncy":   syssize,
     "emod":  Emod,  # Stiffness of fibers in MPa
     "sweib": CharStr,  # Weibull scale parameter of fiber strengths [MPa]
     "mweib": weibullmod,    # Weibull shape parameter of fiber strengths
     "gamma": gamma,      # Range of interaction =0 for GLS and infty for LLS
     "pbs":   pbs}  # periodic boundary conditions 1=switched on

    run={"seed":   seed, #seed for random number generator
     "debug":  True,
     "saveto": "",                   # savepath
     "strain": np.array([0.]),       # strain evolution
     "stress": np.array([0.]),       # stress evolution 
     "avalanchesize":np.array([0.])} # damage evolution
        
    # The main routine for the FBM simulation with variable load range
    lls_mat, strength, stiffness, damage, stress, avalanche, run = init_system( sys, run)  #initialize the system
 
    inc = 0
    nfibs = sys["ncx"] * sys["ncy"] # number of fibers
    load_inc, aval, stress_evo = 0, 0, 0.
    print("Running a FBM with {} fibers with Weibull fiber strength distribution (m,sigma) ({},{}) \n and load sharing parameter gamma={}".format(nfibs,sys["mweib"],sys["sweib"],sys["gamma"]))
    while np.sum(damage) < 0.8*nfibs:         # stop when 80% of the system is broken
        tobreak, stress, stress_inc = increment_strain( strength, stress) # increment the strain on the system and break weakest element
        load_inc += 1 
        stress_evo = stress_evo + stress_inc
        run["strain"] = np.append( run["strain"], stress_evo / sys["emod"]) # store strain
        avalanche[ tobreak[0][0][0], tobreak[0][1][0]] = load_inc           # store damage evolution pattern
        while len( tobreak[0][0] ) > 0:
            stress, strength = load_sharing( sys, lls_mat, tobreak, damage, stress, strength) # redistrirbute load        
            damage = damage_fibers( tobreak, damage)                                          # damage all overloaded fibers
            tobreak, avalanche = new_inc_stress( strength, stress, avalanche, load_inc)       # identify new overloaded fibers
            if (np.sum( damage ) > 0.8 * nfibs): print(">>>Final stop since system is broken"); break # stop when half of the system is broken
            inc += 1
            if ( inc > nfibs ): print("emergency stop something is wrong"); break             # stop when load increments exceed the number of fibers
        run["stress"] = np.append( run["stress"], np.sum( stress * ( 1 - damage ) ) / nfibs ) # store stress
        run["avalanchesize"] = np.append( run["avalanchesize"], np.sum(damage))               # store avalance size

    min_index = np.nonzero( avalanche == 0) # complement list of elemets that fail in the final increment
    tobreak = [ min_index ] 
    for i in range( len( tobreak[0][0] ) ): avalanche[ tobreak[0][0][i], tobreak[0][1][i]] = load_inc
        
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,6)); plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.3); plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.3) # plots for a single realization
    pcm1=ax[0,0].imshow(avalanche); ax[0,0].set_title("damage evolution");   
    pcm2=ax[0,1].imshow(lls_mat); ax[0,1].set_title("load sharing");  
    fig.colorbar(pcm1,ax=ax[0,0],label='# of iterations'), fig.colorbar(pcm2,ax=ax[0,1],label='load sharing portion')
    ax[1,0].plot(run["strain"], run["stress"]); ax[1,0].set_title("stess-strain plot");  ax[1,0].set_xlabel('$\\varepsilon$ [-]');  ax[1,0].set_ylabel('$\\sigma$'); 
    ax[1,1].plot(run["strain"], run["avalanchesize"]/nfibs); ax[1,1].set_title("broken area fraction-strain plot");  ax[1,1].set_xlabel('$\\varepsilon$ [-]'); ax[1,1].set_ylabel('$A_{broken}/A_{tot}$'); 
    plt.show()
    return avalanche
```

But then I dont know how to include the Miners rule and Wöhler curvers and how to consider corrosion.
I had an idea to include the corrosion but I dont really know if it's right and where and how to include it in the code:

```
fiber_position = [[(row,col) for col in range(ncy)] for row in range(ncx)] 
fiber_diameters = d_0 - c * fiber_position   #d_0 is initial fiber diameter, c is corrosion rate parameter
```